# Quick peek at recently used commands in OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to quickly take a look at the most recent commands executed in a terminal window on OSX (10.8.5 if that matters)?

I am thinking about something like <kbd>F7</kbd> in Windows Command Prompt:

[image: Peek at recent commands in command prompt]

I know I can use

```
open .bash_history
cat .bash_history
```

to get my history (not including the current session) and also about the `history` command, but I am looking for an even simpler method, like the one-key solution in Windows Command Prompt.

Also: I am not looking for a method of running those commands (e.g.: with using `!`), but only to have a quick view of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an alias:

```
alias h="history|head"
```

Then you can just type

```
h
```

Add it into `~/.bash_profile` so it is avilable in every session.